# RSA authentication and CSRF attacks

Tags: rsa, csrf

If I use RSA authentication for my web app would I still need to take care of CSRF attacks by using tokens or RSA authentication will take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

that depends on your implementation ... rsa itself has nothing to do with csrf ...

an authentication schema **can** provide some protection (for example if you let the user sign all of it's inputs), but honestly: what's the deal with protecting user inputs from csrf?

on the server side, on login create a salt stored within the users session, calculate hash(current_timestamp, salt) everytime you need to protect a user input, and give that value + the current_timestamp as hidden field to the form ... when you receive the user input, get the salt, and recalculate the value ... if that one matches with what you got from the client, it is unlikely that the input came through csrf ...

since you never expose the salt to the user, there is no way (except taking it directly from your session database which means a compromised system) for the user or an attacker to obtain that salt ...